# BaseAdapter: ViewHolder/Recycle + SwipeListView = trouble

Tags: android, performance, baseadapter, recycle, android-viewholder

**Using BaseAdapter without recycling** (inflating views everytime getView(...) is called) my animation and functionality to swipe inside my list item works fine (it also has images thats loading from web).

```
@Override
public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {

    View view = myViews.get( position );
    final Promotion i = getItem( position );
    view = a.getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.butik_item, parent, false );
    /* More code */
    }
}
```

**Experience:** Poor performance and scrolling is not smooth, **animation + swipe works.**

---

**Using BaseAdapter with Recycling** (array with views and nullchecks with ViewHolder)

```
Map<Integer, View> myViews = new HashMap<Integer, View>();

@Override public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    View v = myViews.get( position );

    if ( v == null ) {
        v = a.getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.butik_item, parent, false );
        /* More code */
    }

    v.setTag( position + "" );
    myViews.put( position, v );
}
```

**Experience:** Great performance and scrolling is smooth, **animations do not work and swipe is veeeery laggy.**

---

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What is the purpose of `myViews`?

Comment: I updated my question so that its more clear. It's used to recycle the views instead of creating new ones.

Comment: That is what `convertView` is for..

Comment: If I use `if ( convertView == null )` and then inflate in that view then I get the same views for every item. Edit: Not every item, but 3/5 is the same depending on scrollposition.

Comment: If your `ListView` needs to have more than one row type you need to override `getItemViewType(int position)` and `getViewTypeCount()`

Comment: It has only one rowtype but its showing the same picture and other information. Its basically a copy of another row.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean. If you want we can chat about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68355/discussion-between-jonas-b-and-emmanuel).